# Find the likelihood threshold for a Goodness-of-Fit test for multinomial data

Tags: likelihood, goodness-of-fit, computational-statistics

Given a sample size $n \in \mathbb{N}$, a null hypothesis $H_0 = \langle p_1, p_2, \dots p_k\rangle$ which is an element of the $k$-dimensional probability simplex, and a significance threshold $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, let $D \sim \mathop{Mult}_k(n, H_0)$, in other words, let $D$ be drawn from the multinomial distribution with $n$ trials and event probabilities $ p_1, p_1, \dots p_k$.

Then, there exists some maximal $t \in (0,1)$ such that $\Pr\limits_D[\mathcal{L}(H_0|D) < t] \leq \alpha$, i.e., such that the probability of the event "the likelihood of $D$ occuring as the result of a draw from a multinomial distribution distributed under $H_0$ is less than t" is less than or equal to $\alpha$.

How can I find this $t$ efficently?  I can find it with a greedy search of all possible values of $D$, but that's extremely slow ($O(n^k)$), and I can find an approximate value for it with Monte Carlo.  Is there a better way?

Comment: There's a disconnect here, because sums are not generally counts.  Your substitution of one for the other suggests there's more going on than you have yet disclosed.  If you would provide details of your situation, we might be able to offer effective answers.  Until then, your question is far too general for any specific answer.

Comment: @whuber sorry, I'm not quite sure of the correct terminology, but I have a very specific type of problem in mind - I have $N$ datapoints, each of which consists only of a single element of the set $\{v_1, v_2, \dots v_k\}$.  My data $D$ is of the form $\langle c_1, c_2, \dots c_k \rangle$, where, for example, a value of $\langle 3, 1, 2 \rangle$ would mean that three data points were $v_1$, one was $v_2$, and two were $v_3$.  I thought this type of problem was completely specified by "goodness of fit", but perhaps not.

Comment: Consider modifying this post to describe your data, how you obtained them, and what the hypothesis (and its alternative) are.  That will be one of the surest ways to communicate your question to our audience.

Comment: I'd appreciate if anyone has some advice on what else I can do to improve this question, since I think I have fully specified what I'm asking?

Comment: When you pose a question this abstractly, *every part of it has to be rigorously correct and clear,* because it provides no clues for us to figure out what you might mean in case any part of it is ambiguous.  I, for one, cannot make sense of your sentence beginning "there exists some maximal $t$..."  It doesn't help that the notation is undefined, non-standard, and vague. What is "$\mathcal L$"?  What does "$Mult_k$" mean?  What is $H_0$ specifically? I can make guesses but they might differ from someone else's guesses and from your intended meanings.

Comment: That's fair, I took this notation from an undergrad stats textbook, but it may be less standard than I had assumed.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Thank you for the edits (+1).  They really clear things up.